# How to disable Alert volume from the command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome, pulseaudio

There is an option in the *Sound Preferences* dialog, *Sound Effects* tab, to toggle Alert volume *mute*.  It works and suffices for my needs to disable the irritating system beep/bell.

However, I reinstall systems a LOT for testing purposes and would like to set this setting in a shell script so it's off without having to fiddle with a GUI.  But for the life of me I can't seem to find where this can be toggled via a command line tool.

I've scanned through `gconf-editor`, PulseAudio's `pacmd`, `grep`ped through `/etc`, even dug through the `gnome-volume-control` source code, but I am not seeing how this can be set.

I gather that `gnome-volume-control` has changed since a few releases ago.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Option 0: (this might be what you were looking for)

  ```
  sudo su gdm -c "gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/sound/event_sounds --type bool false"
  ```
- Option 1:

  Temporary:

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
  ```

  Permanent

  ```
  echo “blacklist pcspkr” >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
  ```
- Option 2:

  Search for "set bell-style" in `/etc/inputrc` (options are `none` or `visible`)
- Option 3:

  ```
  sudo mv -v /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/*.ogg {*.disabled}
  ```
- Option 4:

  ```
  man xset
  ```

Comment: I've actually already done that, but the Alert bell comes through the audio speakers via pulseaudio, not the on-board PC speaker (which I left unplugged in the case anyway).

Comment: It seems to me that a few releases back this could be controlled via gconf, but I didn't see anything with gconftool-2 or gconf-editor.  There is also a pacmd utility for manipulating sound settings, which *seems* like it should be the right tool but I can't discern what sequence of commands would result in toggling that setting.  (I tried running `pacmd info` before and after toggling the Alert mute and diffing the output, but didn't see anything relevant.)

Comment: Hmm, it would be nice if the downvoters said why they downvoted so I could "fix" the answer...

Comment: This makes no difference for the alert event sound on Ubuntu 18.04 with pulseaudio.

Answer (score 13):

Hunted for this for a long while. Especially since I do not use pulseaudio and I cannot mute the alert sound from the UI (WTF!?)

This does it. Oh the sweet joy of silence!

```
# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

Comment: This makes no difference for the alert event sound on Ubuntu 18.04 with pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that lets me adjust volume easily using the `pacmd` and `pactl` commands. Seems to work well when I'm using a GNOME desktop, (Wayland or Xorg), and it's working on RHEL/Fedora and Ubuntu so far. I haven't tried using it with other desktops/distros, or with surround sound systems, etc.

Drop it in your path, and run it without any values to see the current volume. Alternatively set the volume by passing it a percentage. A single value sets both speakers, two values will set left, and right separately. In theory you shouldn't use a value outside of 0%-200%, but the command will let you set the volume higher than 200%, which may harm your speakers, so be careful.

```bsh
[~]# volume
L    R   
20%  20% 
[~]# volume 100% 50%
[~]# volume
L    R   
100% 50% 
[~]# volume 80%
[~]# volume
L    R   
80%  80%
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -z "$1" ] && [ $# -eq 1 ] && export LVOL="$1" && export RVOL="$1"
[ ! -z "$1" ] && [ ! -z "$2" ] && [ $# -eq 2 ]  && export LVOL="$1" && export RVOL="$2"

SINK=$(pacmd list-sinks | grep -e '* index:' | grep -Eo "[0-9]*$")

if [ -z "$LVOL" ] || [ -z "$RVOL" ]; then
  # pacmd list-sinks | grep -e '* index:' -A 20 | grep -e 'name:' -e '^\s*volume:.*\n' -e 'balance' --color=none
  printf "%-5s%-4s\n%-5s%-4s\n" "L" "R" $(pacmd list-sinks | grep -e '* index:' -A 20 | grep -e '^\s*volume:.*\n' --color=none | grep -Eo "[0-9]*%" | tr  "\n" " " | sed "s/ $/\n/g")
  exit 0
elif [[ ! "$LVOL" =~ ^[0-9]*%$ ]] || [[ ! "$RVOL" =~ ^[0-9]*%$ ]]; then
  printf "The volume should specified as a percentage, from 0%% to 200%%.\n"
  exit 1
elif [ "$SINK" == "" ]; then
  printf "Unable to find the default sound output.\n"
  exit 1
fi

pactl -- set-sink-volume $SINK $LVOL $RVOL
```

Comment: Hi! While I think that this is a nice and useful script (tested it and it works great), it doesn't really answer the question, which is about *"How to disable Alert volume from the command line"*, not the sound volume in general. So, I would kindly suggest that you ask a new question which you can answer yourself with this script/answer! Otherwise, this answer might be deleted for not directly answering the question, and we would then lose a fine answer. Thanks for your contribution and I'm looking forward to upvoting your new Q&A! :)

Comment: It stops alerts from making noise on my setup....

Comment: BeastOfCaerbannog does it need to target a different output sink on your system?

Comment: My point is that the script changes the global volume, not only the volume of alerts. What is the part of your script that specifically targets the alerts volume?

Comment: I blieve someone else mentioned it already, but: `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds false` will disable. To actually control it, is system specific. On my system you can send control commands using `notify-send` ....

Comment: I should probably add that the alert volume is subordinate to the master volume. So lowering the master 20% with alerts at 100% gives you 20% volume. With master at 20%, and alerts at 20% you get 4% volume.