# Disable sounds in Nautilus

Tags: sound, nautilus, 12.10, notification

With upgrade to Quantal, Nautilus makes some sounds when moving between folders and when closing folder properties window.
I have all sounds disabled from System Settings (muted) and didn't find any relevant options from Nautilus preferences.
How to remove them?

I will also consider hacks (eg. replacing sound files with silent ones).

Comment: Have a look at this question:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/25531/how-to-disable-alert-volume-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same "issue" on 14.04.Go to Preferences(System Settings) > Sound > Sound Effects and mute the alert.